# HERE geocoding transactions not showing up on the usage page

Tags: transactions, geocoding, here-api

I created an account with HERE yesterday, and I've been geocoding using the REST API. I know I'm not close to my transaction limit, but I've probably geocoded ~10,000 localities, and I'm getting to the point where I'd really like to know how much of the monthly quota I have used up.

For some reason, my transactions are not showing up on my usage page: it still shows 0 transactions, even though I know I have many more than that.
[Here's a screenshot:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VKhuG.png)

Does anyone know why my transactions aren't displaying? Perhaps there is a delay after creating the account, and they will display after a few days?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check FAQs ( https://developer.here.com/faqs#payment-and-subscription ). Point 7 ( "Why can't I see usage for my app in the Usage Details section of my Project Details page") informs about delay between api usage and visibility on dashboard.

Comment: Thank you! I don't know how I missed that. As of today, it still hasn't shown up, but hopefully it will by tomorrow.

Comment: Just wanted to check with you, did usage appear on UI at the end?

Comment: Yes, it did eventually show up! Thanks for checking in.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can take up to a day for transactions to show up in the dashboard.